# Is there any PHP OO file API?

Tags: php, oop, filesystems

I know that PHP includes a lot of built-in functions for handling files and directories. I can read, write, delete, and I can get almost any possible information about files thru the use of **[PHP filesystem functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.filesystem.php)**
the problem with these functions are that *they are all procedural.*

**Is there any PHP OO file API ?**

I doubt that there is a native one, at least in < 5.3. I am looking for some 3rd party extension or class to achieve this.

Comment: Good question. This is really useful for unit testing classes that access the filesystem, too.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, [yes there is](http://php.net/manual/en/class.splfileobject.php), and it is beautiful. [SplFileInfo](http://php.net/manual/en/class.splfileinfo.php) and [SplFileObject](http://php.net/manual/en/class.splfileobject.php) (which is the one you probably really want) were both available in 5.1.2.

While they are mostly just wrappers around procedural functionality, I find them far nicer overall -- if only because they allow me to pass things around while using type-hinting, and because I don't need to worry about fclose.

I guess it's similar to the PDO classes. Yes, you can do things procedurally, but why would you?

Comment: **NO**. Both of those classes are *experimental* and even worse, `SplFileObject` is for **text files**.

Comment: Apparently, they're not experimental classes anymore, but `SplFileObject` is still limited to text files: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=36289

Comment: @Christian `fpassthru` will suffice in most cases.

Comment: If I wanted to get that way, why bother with OOP? Might as well use `file_get_contents()`, no?

Answer (score 2):

In 5.3 you can use [SPLFileObject](https://www.php.net/splfileobject).

Answer (score 1):

Oh god no, procedural, the horrors! But in fact there are [`SplFileObject`](http://php.net/SplFileObject) and [`SplFileInfo`](http://php.net/SplFileInfo) and [`SplTempFileObject`](http://php.net/SplTempFileObject), albeit they only map the base functions partially.

There is no comparable directory API, but e.g. [`RecursiveDirectoryIterator`](http://php.net/RecursiveDirectoryIterator) can be used for reading. For a traversal API look into Hordes/PEARs [VFS](http://pear.php.net/package/VFS).

Comment: There are some genuine problems with procedural APIs. For example, it's nice to be able to write automated tests against critical code without actually having that code modify things on the disk. You can mock an OOP filesystem API, but you can't with a procedural one. Still +1 for being the only answer to include directories.